# Session variable not destroyed on timeout?

Tags: yii2

I have the following code in config

```
'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\UserCustomer',
            'authTimeout' => 30,
        ],
```

after 30 second of inactivity, and I refresh the browser the account logged out indicate with login link appear, but some variable which display from session remain exists in my view.

Here is my partial code in view

```
<?php
                        $lsproduk = Yii::$app->session['produkcart'];
                        //echo "counter awal Yii::$app->session['counter']";
                        if(isset (Yii::$app->session['counter']))
                        {

                            foreach($lsproduk as $key => $produk){

                                if(VwProdukAgent::find()->where(['produk_agen_id' => $produk->produk_agen_id])->andWhere(['is_active_produk_agent' => false])->count() > 0){
                                    unset($lsproduk[$key]);
                                }
                            }

                            Yii::$app->session['produkcart'] = $lsproduk;

                            $lsproduk = Yii::$app->session['produkcart'];

                            Yii::$app->session['counter'] = count($lsproduk);

                            $counter = Yii::$app->session['counter'];
                            //display total product
                            echo "<span class='cart-count'>$counter</span></a>";

                        } 
                    ?>
```

Refresh few time doesn't solve the problem.

It's different when I normaly press logout button, there is no variable displayed in view.

for your information my current application is e-commerce, the variable which displayed on timeout is total product on cart which is from session. it's different when I normally press logout, the cart is empty of course because session get destroyed on logout method.

Is something wrong? let me know about it.

*UPDATED*

Then how I can delete other session variable on timeout?

Comment: `authTimeout` in `user` component does not affect other session variables.

Comment: @Bizley thanks for explanation, question updated :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same mechanism as in [yii\web\User](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.10/framework/web/User.php#L634) component.

1. Add the parameter to keep the time of session expiration (like `cartExpire`).
2. When creating cart add this parameter to the session setting it to current timestamp plus 30 seconds:
   `Yii::$app->getSession()->set('cartExpire', time() + 30);`
3. When accessing the cart session check this parameter and if it's less than current timestamp it means the session expired and you can drop the cart.
4. When cart is updated remember to update this parameter as well again for next 30 seconds.